# Python (Perl-type) regex lookahead/lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Consider a string `s = "aa,bb11,22  ,     33  , 44,cc , dd     "`.

I would like to split `s` into the following list of tokens using the [regular expressions module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) in **Python**, which is similar to the functionality offered by Perl:

1. `"aa,bb11"`
2. `"22"`
3. `"33"`
4. `"44,cc , dd     "`

Note:

- I want to tokenise on commas, but only if those commas have numbers to either side.
- Any (optional) whitespace around these "numerical commas" that I'm targeting should be removed in the result.  The optional whitespace may be more than a single space.
- Any other whitespace should be left as it appears in the original string.

My best attempt so far is the following:

```
import re

pattern = r'(?<=\d)(\s*),(\s*)(?=\d)'
s = 'aa,bb11,22 , 33 , 44,cc , dd '

print re.compile(pattern).split(s)
```

but this prints:

```
['aa,bb11', '', '', '22', ' ', ' ', '33', ' ', ' ', '44,cc , dd ']
```

which is close to what I want, inasmuch as the 4 things I want are contained in the list.  I could go through and get rid of any empty strings and any strings that consist of only spaces/commas, but I'd rather have a single line regex that does all this for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put capture groups on the `\s*`:

```
pattern = r'(?<=\d)\s*,\s*(?=\d)'
```

Comment: @Ωmega Look again. It's not doing both, it's using the regex TO split.  Otherwise what's being split on?

Comment: @Ωmega split is a regex operation but so is findall.  Split is what was being asked for.  Tested both and regardless of the fact that both are "fast enough", your approach is slower then mVChr 's posted here even after adjusting for the slower compile time of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Don't group the \s*, and they won't be captured and written in the output:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'aa,bb11,22 , 33 , 44,cc , dd '
>>> re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(\s*),(\s*)(?=\d)').split(s)
['aa,bb11', '', '', '22', ' ', ' ', '33', ' ', ' ', '44,cc , dd ']
>>> re.compile(r'(?<=\d)\s*,\s*(?=\d)').split(s)
['aa,bb11', '22', '33', '44,cc , dd ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex and split - that is too complicated. See this >>

```
import re
s = "aa,bb11,22 , 33 , 44,cc , dd "
result = re.findall(ur"(?:^\s*|(?<=\d)\s*,\s*)(.*?)(?=\s*,\s*\d|\s*$)", s)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['aa,bb11', '22', '33', '44,cc , dd']
```

*Test it [here](http://ideone.com/O3KY5).*

Comment: If you want to keep trailing white-space character in the last match (what I believe you don't), then replace `\s*$` in the regex pattern with `$` only. Similar change applies for leading white-space characters in the first match (there are none in your example), so if you want keep those spaces, then replace `^\s*` with `^` only.

Answer (score 0):

You are using capturing parentheses the extra white space in between is what was captured by the two `(\s*)` you can use non-capturing parentheses like this:

```
r'(?<=\d)(?:\s*),(?:\s*)(?=\d)'
```

although, the parentheses are not really needed at all